# spring boot - SecurityFilterChain : permitAll() does not work normally in the requestMatchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to access no login access "/" and "/auth/**" so I make my code like it

---

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authz->
                    authz
                            .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/auth/loginForm");
        return http.build();
    }
```

---

but When I go to the "localhost/" or "localhost/auth/joinForm", but a login Popup appears.
anyRequest() apply to all paths.
Is my code wrong?

### Below is the complete code.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration //bean 등록
@EnableWebSecurity //시큐리티에 Filter 추가
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false) //특정 주소로 접근시 권한 미리 체크하겠다
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authz->
                    authz
                            .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()`your text`
                );
        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Access is made without login when accessing "/" and "/auth/*", and login is required when accessing other pages.

Comment: try to use antMatchers() then write your pattern see if it work

Comment: I solved it. After it added my jsp path, it was solved

Comment: @cocokik it would be helpful if you can post your solution as an answer so others who have a similar problem can see it.

Comment: This sounds like it could be related to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_permit_forward_when_using_spring_mvc

Answer (score -1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //todo auto generated
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()

        .and().formLogin()
    }
  

}
```

Comment: extend the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Class and override the configure(httpSecurity http) and use antMatchers("/").permitAll()